# Vue - Loop through an array with nested objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, object, v-for

I'm fetching a list that I'm trying to loop through that has an object inside. I'm using vue and the array looks like this:

```
companies: [
  name: "company1"
  id: 1
  type: "finance"
  additionalData: "{"funder":"blabla","idType":5,"number":"2"}"
]
```

My problem is accessing the different ones inside the additionalData.

This is how far I've come:

```
        <div
            v-for="(company, idx) in companies"
            :key="idx"
        >
          <p class="font-weight-bold text-h6"> {{ company.name }} </p>
          <p class="font-weight-bold"> {{ company.additionalData.funder }} </p>
        </div>
```

This doesn't work and I've tried a loop inside the loop aswell. When I only print out {{ company.additionalData }} I get the whole object. Can it have something to do with that the object is inside a string? Could I do a computed or something to figure this out or? :)

Comment: I think you have a few syntax errors wrong with your code. you say that `companies` is an array, but it contains keys and values separated by colons, which is not valid inside an array, so you should have `companies: { ... }` rather than `companies: [ ... ]`. Also, the line with `additionalData` doesn't make sense. you have strings like "{" directly next to variables like `funder` and `blabla`. I'm wondering if this was just an issue with how you copy pasted your code into StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right, you can't access json properties with dot notation in html. You can fix that with `JSON.parse`, which will turn your JSON object into a JavaScript object that you can access the properties of in your template.

```js
companies: {
  name: "company1"
  id: 1
  type: "finance"
  additionalData: JSON.parse("{"funder":"blabla","idType":5,"number":"2"}")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like additionalData is a string containing JSON, so try converting the string to an object. Something like this should work:

```
<p class="font-weight-bold"> {{ JSON.parse(company.additionalData).funder }} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax problem

```
companies: [
  name: "company1"
  id: 1
  type: "finance"
  additionalData: {
    "funder": "blabla",
    "idType": 5,
    "number":"2"
  }
]
```